# WebSockets -- Max frame size

Tags: websocket, netty

I just stumbled over this (old) mail:

http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg07655.html

"If a frame is sent that a server is unable to buffer for whatever reason, I would expect the server to close the connection with error code 1004".

The RFC says:

```
1004
  Reserved.  The specific meaning might be defined in the future.
```

How does Netty handle to large Messages?

Answer (score 2):

This has already been taken into account in Netty 3.4.2.

Basically, you can optionally supply your `maxFramePayloadLength` to the constructor of `WebSocketServerHandshaker`.

Please see pull request https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/283.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/veebs/netty/blob/763f22463efa3b710feae4cde6eb62d1fdfd0235/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java#L229.  It will throw a protocol exception which will force the socket to be closed.

Comment: I believe this is acceptable under RFC 6455 section 10.7. Handling of Invalid Data. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-53